# How to calculate energy gradient and Hessian with respect to only a few internal coordinates using Gaussian?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, electronic-structure, gaussian, geometry-optimization

I would like to form the (numerical) gradient and the Hessian of the total electronic energy with respect only to a few internal coordinates (namely, the six intermolecular coordinates of a weakly bound dimer). In those cases I saw, when second derivatives were calculated, Gaussian always determined the full Hessian. **Do you know an option capable of controlling the set of active variables used to calculate the gradient and the Hessian of reduced size?**

Comment: +1 Gaussian (and most other softwares) determine the analytic hessian for the full wavefunction. If you want hessian for particular coordinates, it can only be done numerically I believe (and it won't be as accurate). If this is what you want, this can be done in Gaussian (https://gaussian.com/opt/  look at the "Options" tab). Are you open to using other QM softwares or only Gaussian?

Comment: @SRMaiti  Thanks for your detailed comments. It is not a problem for me to have numerical partial derivatives: they are accurate enough to make a reduced dimensional optimization for (higher-order) saddle points. I also saw the option "Diff" and tried to use it, but I did not recognize the derivative value in the .log file or the .fchk file. Furthermore, I do not see a similar options for the calculation of gradient components. Another problem is that the option "Diff" determines all the Hessian entries contained in the row/column of a particular internal coordinate.

Comment: @SRMaiti (As mentioned in the question,I do not need for the "coupling" between inter- and intramolecular coordinates".) I do not insist on using Gaussian, but the other software is expected to calculate the MP2/aug-cc-pVTZ energies in parallel and as fast as Gaussian does.

Comment: if you can calculate the numerical hessian, then you can transform the Hessian into internal coordinates and project into the space of the ICs that you care about. From there you can back transform to Cartesians or get force constants etc.

Comment: @CodyAldaz I do not quite understand what you wrote, sorry. What kind of Hessian can I calculate? I would like to determine only a few entries of the full Hessian, given in internal coordinates, without calculating the full Hessian matrix.

Comment: @TobiR Gaussian's opt page (the one I linked) mentions that it can numerically differentiate for particular internal coordinates like bonds, angles etc. but it only does a one-sided displacement for the differentiation; this is for the starting guess hessian. You have to then somehow get Gaussian to dump this initial hessian (it will be the full hessian, but the other entries will be guessed) and then extract the internal coordinates you specified using the method Cody mentioned. I don't have access to Gaussian right now, so I can't help more sorry.

Comment: You should also check out Orca. It can also calculate hessians for particular sets of internal coordinates, and it does a two-sided displacement i.e. is slightly more accurate. However, one limitation is that it only takes atom numbers, and it will calculate all internal coordinates involving those atoms (i.e. you cannot specify bonds, angles etc. you can only select atoms). Orca can do MP2 calculations in parallel, not sure if it's faster or slower than Gaussian though.

Comment: @CodyAldaz Perhaps you could expand that comment into an answer? Our unanswered queue recently blew up into 4 pages when using the 50 questions/page, and it might be nice to get it back down to a more manageable 3 pages :)

Comment: @CodyAldaz any chance you could write an answer? TobiR, would S R Matiti's suggestion of using ORCA be possible for you? Has there been any luck/update on this? The question has been in our unanswered queue for over 6 months and it would be nice to have it updated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its abandoned